# How to get data from server and use a hook to retrieve it in multiple components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, react-hooks

I have a rather basic use-case: I want to get the user info from the server when the app loads and then using a hook to get the info in different components.

For some reason, I run into an infinite loop and get `Error: Maximum update depth exceeded.`
`getMe` gets called recursively until the app crashes.
Is that a correct hook behavior?

This is the relevant part of the hook:

```js
export default function useUser () {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const [authenticating, setAuthenticating] = useState(true)

  // ...

  const getMe = (jwt) => {
    console.log('set user')
    axios.get(baseURL + endpoints.currentUser, { headers: {
      'X-Access-Token': jwt,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }}).then(response => {
      setUser({
        name: response.data.name,
        img: response.data.avatar_url
      })
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getMe(jwt)
  }, [])

  return { user, authenticating }
}
```

This is the first call

```js
function App () {
  const { user, authenticating } = useUser()
  const c = useStyles()

  return (
    authenticating ? (
      <div className={c.wrapper}>
        <Loader size={60}/>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div className={c.wrapper}>
        <div className={c.sidebar}>
          <img className={c.lamp} src={ user ? user.img : lamp } />
```

And I also call need the user in the Router component

```
const Routes = () => {
  const { user } = useUser()

  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        // ...
        <Route
          path={pages.login}
          render={routeProps => (
            user ?
              <Redirect to={pages.main}/> :
              <Login {...routeProps}/>
          )}
        />
```

Comment: [Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). useUser function seems to be breaking that rule

Comment: Where? I call it only in component functions

Comment: An object is returned from useUser(invalid react element) and it is getting used as a plain javascript function instead of rendering something. It doesn't look like [function component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components). This might/might not be causing the issue but official docs says to avoid this

Comment: Thanx but I still don't understand which part of my code you are referring to.

Comment: I am talking about useState and useEffect hooks. `const [user, setUser] = useState(null) const [authenticating, setAuthenticating] = useState(true) useEffect(() => {
    getMe(jwt)
  }, [])` ^^ all this code inside `useUser` function

Comment: You are mixing things up. Hooks don't return components they return state.

Comment: ilyo can you show where you use Routes?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be requesting the server each time you call the hook since it pretty much unnecessary. You could use Redux or context for this (for this paradigm redux would be better).  However, if you insist on this method, it seems you have to wrap your `getMe` function in a `useCallback` hook since it must be re-rendering each time the function runs.

Read more on the `useCallback` hook:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Answer (score 0):

You're now making a request via the `useEffect` in your custom hook - why not let the component do that programatically?

Change `getMe` to a `useCallback` function and export it:

```
export default function useUser () {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const [authenticating, setAuthenticating] = useState(true)

  // ...

  const getMe = useCallback((jwt) => {
    console.log('set user')
    axios.get(baseURL + endpoints.currentUser, { headers: {
      'X-Access-Token': jwt,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }}).then(response => {
      setUser({
        name: response.data.name,
        img: response.data.avatar_url
      })
    })
  }, [])

  return { user, authenticating, doFetch: getMe }
}
```

..and use that function in your components (import `doFetch` and call it on mount), e. g.:

```
function App () {
  const { user, authenticating, doFetch } = useUser()
  const c = useStyles()

  useEffect(() => doFetch(), [doFetch])

  return (
    authenticating ? (
      <div className={c.wrapper}>
        <Loader size={60}/>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div className={c.wrapper}>
        <div className={c.sidebar}>
          <img className={c.lamp} src={ user ? user.img : lamp } />
```

You now avoid the infinite loop and your component takes control of the request logic instead of the reusable hook.